# Quartz Scheduler next execution time equal current time plus interval of scheduler

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I am working with Quartz scheduler and everything work perfect according to the requirement. But there one thing that I want to implement and i.e. I want my **next execution** of job will trigger on **(currentFinishTime + intervalOfScheduler)**

Example of job execution with 30 seconds of interval:

> Job-1-First-Executed at 10-10-2020 18:30:05
> Job-1-Second-Executed at 10-10-2020 18:30:35
> Job-1-Third-Executed at 10-10-2020 18:31:05

So, here if the job takes 20 seconds to execute then next trigger will happen on 05+20+30 = 55. Instead of 10-10-2020 18:30:35, it will trigger at 10-10-2020 18:30:55 and same for other execution and so on...

Note: `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` and `MyJobExecutor implements Job {public void execute(JobExecutionContext context){...}}` are already implemented.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lots of research, I have implemented my own solution which suffice my requirement. The code is mentioned below:

```
if(isExecutionTimeIncluded) {
    final TriggerBuilder triggerBuilder = context.getTrigger().getTriggerBuilder();
    final Trigger newTrigger = triggerBuilder
                  .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                  .withIntervalInSeconds(cpoPullJobData.getInterval())
                                .repeatForever())
                  .startAt(futureDate(interval/*eg.30*/, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.SECOND);)
                  .build();
    context.getScheduler().rescheduleJob(context.getTrigger().getKey(), newTrigger);
}
```